# Calculating Top 10 Results in Storm

Tags: redis, apache-storm

I am reading sentences from redis Server and counting the occurrence of each word. Now I want to calculate the top 10 words based on count. I have one Spout to read the sentences from Redis Server, one Bolt that breaks sentences into words and one Bolt that counts the words.

What should be my approach in finding Top 10 Words based on count?

Comment: Because Storm is designed to work on continuous streams, you have to decide what you mean by top 10. Top 10 in the last minute of processing, top 10 in the last 1000 sentences, top 10 ever?

Answer (score 0):

Say if you have to do a top to for last X minute, configure your bolt with tick tuple after every X minutes till then keep on counting words in the bolt. On encountering a tick tuple emit the top ten items, you can keep the counter maintained in an in memory tree map (depending on the usecase and data size)

Now say you have to do a top 10 ever with large data size maintain count in Redis data structure and emit top 10 after every Y seconds based on your need.

For tick tuple refer Michael's blog @ http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/01/18/implementing-real-time-trending-topics-in-storm/

Answer (score 0):

Write the frequency of the words to Redis using a [SortedSet](http://redis.io/topics/data-types). For each word that Storm processes it increments the counter for that word in Redis using [ZINCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/zincrby).

The values in a SortedSet are ordered by value and so you can retrieve the top ten with [ZREVRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrange) like this.

```
ZREVRANGE myset 0-9 WITHSCORES
```